# azure function host.json settings not persistet

Tags: azure-functions

I need to set a higher timeout in an azure function. This works by editing the host.json. I can set the timeout and save it, everything works.

When I deploy the function app, these settings are not available anymore. Any ideas what I can change?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before deploy, open `.csproj` file of your local Azure Function, make sure it shows as below:

```
<None Update="host.json">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
<None Update="local.settings.json">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
</None>
```